# Azure function app ETIMEDOUT error works sometimes but not others

Tags: node.js, azure, request-promise, azure-function-app

I have the below code:

```
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');
module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    var arr = [[url1],[url2]]
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        func(context, arr[i]);
    }
}
function func(context, urls) {
    const promises = urls.map(item => {
        return rp({
            uri: item,
            simple: false,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.statusCode == 403) {

                var msg = "hello";
                return msg;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
        // remove null results from array
        return data.filter(item => item !== null);
    });
}
```

And I keep getting this error. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. How can I fix this, and why does it work sometimes and sometimes not.

```
Result: Failure
Exception: RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Do I need to inclue a `pool` option? Or perhaps a `timeout`? The error seems to be due to the size of `arr`.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Comment: I solved this with `agent: false, pool: { maxSockets: 8 }`

Comment: I update it in my reply. You could accept it as answer or you post another reply to let others know and close this issue.

Comment: Done so, thanks. Can you explain why the agent/socket solution works so I can understand it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue on the network level and has most likely to do with your proxy configuration. And also you may get this error when requesting to a server using `https` (port 443) that didn't have a valid certificate. So, using the the following configuration could solve your problem.

```
return rp({
       uri: item,
       simple: false,
       resolveWithFullResponse: true,
       proxy: 'http://<your.proxy.info>:8080',
       strictSSL :false
})
```

**Update:**

No proxy, no streaming, just single request which starts several async request, setting this options:

```
agent: false, pool: {maxSockets: 8}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would I find my proxy info to try this?

Comment: When do not have a valid certificate, you can confirm this behavior by editing your /etc/hosts (or hosts on Windows) adding a record with IP address and the host Common Name (that you can get check inside certificate) and then make the request again.

Comment: Use  `proxy:'http://username:password@host:port'`. For more, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies).