# Azure Function Deployment fails in Visual Code with ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-functions

I am unable to deploy any Azure Function to the Azure from Visual Studio Code. I have tried to sign out and sign in back to the Azure, restarting Visual Code, creating new functions with different setups, but these didn't help. I am using Visual Studio Professional Subscription's free Azure credit to learn to do develop Azure Functions, but it is difficult when I can't get the deployment work. Any ideas how to fix this or what might be the reason?

It starts deploying and after 30-60 seconds it throws ETIMEDOUT error.

```
Creating zip package...
Zip package size: 2.96 kB
Error: request to https://**********.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true&author=VS%20Code failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Comment: What language do you use? Cause the result I searched  is that's a npm error, and solved by running this command: `npm config delete proxy`.

Comment: I have tried to deploy javascript/node and c#/.NET Core 3.1 Function Apps, but I get the same error each time. Unfortunately `npm config delete proxy` had no effect.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287913/azure-function-app-etimedout-error-works-sometimes-but-not-others